# workbench and phpmyadmin are showing different number of connections

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am running mysql 8.0 on centos 7.4

phpmyadmin and workbench are showing totally different information regarding the number of connections (shown below).
[image: connections from phpmyadmin]

at the sametime this is what I am seeing on workbench:

[image: connections from workbench]

This is what is being shown from inside phpmyadmin regarding the processes:

[image: processes from inside phpmyadmin]

The processes from inside workbench are shown below AND they coincide with the processes from phpmyadmin.

[image]

So why are they showing the same of processes but very different number of connections?

Comment: PMA appears to be plotting the difference in the value of the `Connections` global status variable between requests. Workbench is plotting the number of connections at the time of sampling. Very different metrics.

Comment: I tried to run:
<code>
    show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
    show processlist;
</code>
but I got answers to similar to what workbench is showing. I am wondering on how phpmyadmin is getting these numbers?
can they be cumulative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the payload for the ajax requests you can see the `requiredData`, something like:

```json
{
    "0":[
        [{"type":"statusvar","name":"Questions"}]
    ],
    "1":[
        [{"type":"statusvar","name":"Connections"}],
        [{"type":"proc","name":"processes"}]
    ],
    "2":[
        [{"type":"statusvar","name":"Bytes_sent"}],
        [{"type":"statusvar","name":"Bytes_received"}]
    ],
    "3":[
        [{"type":"cpu","name":"loadavg"}]
    ],
    "4":[
        [{"type":"memory","name":"MemUsed"}],
        [{"type":"memory","name":"MemFree"}]
    ],
    "5":[
        [{"type":"memory","name":"SwapUsed"}],
        [{"type":"memory","name":"SwapFree"}]
    ]
}
```

The vars listed with `"type":"statusvar"` are retrieved using `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name=...`, as can be seen here in [`Server/Status/Monitor.php`](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/961b33951e42208ceda64132c11c7495e33cdaa1/src/Server/Status/Monitor.php#L65):

```php
// Retrieve all required status variables
$statusVarValues = [];
if (count($statusVars)) {
    $statusVarValues = $this->dbi->fetchResult(
        "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name='"
        . implode("' OR Variable_name='", $statusVars) . "'",
        0,
        1
    );
}
```

If you look at [`refreshChartGrid()`](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/961b33951e42208ceda64132c11c7495e33cdaa1/resources/js/src/server/status/monitor.ts#L1552) you can see that PMA is comparing the values received in each ajax call with the values from the previous call. For connections it is using the value of [`Connections`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections), not [`Threads_connected`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) which is used by Workbench.

Comment: Now that is one hell of an answer. Thx a ton. It makes sense now.